# Get closest Point from P1 to P2 when I can only go a distance d

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Unfortunately, I don't know much about this topic, that's why I apologize for my language. I have two points `P1` and `P2`, now I want "to get from one to the other", but I can only go a distance `d`. And I want to get as close as possible from `P1` to `P2`.

Here is an example:

> d=400, P1(0,0), P2(500,500)

Now the formula should give me `P3(282.843, 282.843)`.

This works with the formula $$d = \sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2 + (y_2-y_1)^2}$$ but this only works if `x` and `y` of P3 are equal, and I can't control where `P2` is.

I hope you understand what I mean. This might be a very stupid question, but I don't know how to search for a solution. Maybe you can help me with a keyword for this problem, formatting the answer right or a solution.

Thank you

Comment: will it not just be on the line joining those two points? then you can easily find the coordinates...

Comment: Find the distance from $x\to y$, divide the max distance by it, call that quotient $t$. The answer is $tp_2+(1-t)p_1$.

Comment: @Aditya_math You are right, thanks. Sometimes its so easy.

Comment: But is there a way, to get this from a formuala, like x,y=...? Maybe @DonThousand has the solution, but I dont understand what he means.

Comment: Or is there a way to calculate on which point I am, when I go e.g. 400 "steps" on the graph?

Comment: I found everything I need. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We travel along the straight line $x=y$ where as this line  interporlate the two points. We are interested with the case when $x>0$.

$$2x^2=d^2$$

$$x=\frac{d}{\sqrt2}=200\sqrt2$$

Hence the solution is $(200\sqrt2, 200\sqrt2)$

Comment: Thanks. Does this also work if x != y?

Comment: use the same idea that it lies on the straight line, the rest are computational details.

Comment: Okay, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Although Siong Thye Goh already provided the [correct answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4139525/918887), I wanted to show the answer explicitly in parametric form.

Let $\vec{p}_0$ be the starting point, $\vec{p}_1$ the target, and $d$ the distance one can travel.

If $d \ge \lVert \vec{p}_1 - \vec{p}_0 \rVert$, one can travel from $\vec{p}_0$ to $\vec{p}_1$.  Otherwise, one can travel only to $\vec{p}$,
$$\vec{p} = \vec{p}_0 + \left( \vec{p}_1 - \vec{p}_0 \right) \frac{d}{\left\lVert \vec{p}_1 - \vec{p}_0 \right\rVert} \tag{1}\label{G1}$$
where $\lVert\vec{v}\rVert = \sqrt{\vec{v} \cdot \vec{v}} = \sqrt{\sum_i v_i^2}$ is the Euclidean norm (length) of vector $\vec{v}$.

In two dimensions, with $\vec{p} = (x, y)$, $\vec{p}_0 = (x_0, y_0)$, and $\vec{p}_1 = (x_1, y_1)$,
$$\lambda = \frac{d}{\sqrt{ (x_1 - x_0)^2 + (y_1 - y_0)^2 }}$$ and $$\left\lbrace \begin{aligned}
x &= (1 - \lambda) x_0 + \lambda x_1 \\
y &= (1 - \lambda) y_0 + \lambda y_1 \\
\end{aligned} \right.$$
and in three dimensions,
$$\lambda = \frac{d}{\sqrt{ (x_1 - x_0)^2 + (y_1 - y_0)^2 + (z_1 - z_0)^2 }} \\
$$and$$\left\lbrace \begin{aligned}
x &= (1 - \lambda) x_0 + \lambda x_1 \\
y &= (1 - \lambda) y_0 + \lambda y_1 \\
z &= (1 - \lambda) z_0 + \lambda z_1 \\
\end{aligned} \right.$$
noting that $(1-\lambda) x_0 + \lambda x_1 = x_0 + \lambda ( x_1 - x_0 )$; where $\lambda$ is just a temporary parameter ("lambda", for "length scale factor").

In a computer program that uses floating-point numbers the first form is preferable, because the latter form can suffer from domain cancellation.  When say $x_1$ is large in magnitude and $x_0$ relatively small in magnitude (so much closer to zero), $x_1 - x_0 = x_1$ using floating_point numbers due to the finite precision!  Then, at very small $\lambda$ ($d$ very small compared to the distance between $\vec{p}_0$ and $\vec{p}_1$), $x = 0$ and not $x_0$.  Similarly for the case when $x_0$ is close to zero, and $x_1$ is very large, and for the other Cartesian coordinates.  Using $(1 - \lambda)$ and $\lambda$ avoids the domain cancellation (because it calculates the contribution of each point separately), so this is precise near both the start and end points, regardless of the numerical magnitudes.